# test() in Yup returning error even values are not equal

Tags: formik, yup

I am doing a password validation schema, and I've got the following

```
const ProfileEditSchema = t =>
    Yup.object().shape({
       
        password: Yup.string()
            .notRequired(t('TR_PASSWORD_REQUIRED'))
            .matches(
                /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%-.()_']{8,}$/,
                t('TR_PASSWORD_HELPER')
            ),
        new_password: Yup.string().when('password', {
            is: password => password != undefined,
            then: Yup.string()
                .required(t('TR_PASSWORD_REQUIRED'))
                .matches(
                    /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%-.()_']{8,}$/,
                    t('TR_PASSWORD_HELPER')
                )
                .test(
                    'password-not-equal',
                    'new and old password are the same',
                    (password, new_password) => password === new_password
                )
        })
```

});

Everything works fine except my test function which whenever I set a new password value it keeps giving me the validation message error=> 'new and old password are the same' even I set different passwords.
Also would appreciate if you can tell if using `.test()` in this case is the best aproach.
All I want is to throw error in case two input values are equals.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Noticed that you can't use other fields values as new_password in a .test() and also solutions explained as const {new_password}=this.parent, to get other fields value inside test didn't work because this returned undefined.
So according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56241892/yup-compare-field-itself-with-another-field) I used in my code and substituted:

Instead of:

```
.test('password-not-equal','new and old password are the same',
          (password, new_password) => password === new_password)
```

I wrote:

```
.when('password', (password, schema) => {
                    return schema.test({
                        test: new_password => new_password !== password,
                        message: 'Passwords must be different'
                    });
                })
```